# How does browser know which element my mouse's cursor is pointing?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, dom-events

I'm reading some posts about dom event propagation and I get it. However I'm really curious about **how the browser know which document element has been clicked** (or cursor is over).

I assume that operation system offer some special interface by which browser can get the coordinate of the pointer of mouse. If so, browser can just calculate which document element is under the pointer of mouse, right? **Why does need to browser implement event propagation**? Does it just for knowing interaction happened on descendant element so then can inform the ancestor?

*I'll appreciate any ref or comments supported.*

Comment: You might as well ask how *any* program interacts with the mouse cursor…!? Each system and each browser may have its own way how *exactly* it does things. I think that's a bit too broad to explain in detail. But yes, take it for granted that the browser knows where the mouse cursor is when clicked. The event propagation mechanism is a separate topic from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does browser know which element my mouse's cursor is pointing?

The same way Word et. al. know where the cursor is in your document.

> I assume that operation system offer some special interface by which browser can get the coordinate of the pointer of mouse.

It's not "special," but yes, the OS notifies an application where the mouse is.

> If so, browser can just calculate which document element is under the pointer of mouse, right?

Yes. That's what it does.

> Why does need to browser implement event propagation?

It doesn't *have* to other than that's what's defined in the [DOM specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) and the [DOM UI Events specification](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/), because it's really useful to have that propagation. You can learn more about it from [this section](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-flow) of the DOM UI Events specification, which among other things has this lovely diagram which terrifically aided my understanding of this process years ago:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

when u click on DOM elements u want to have control
check pictures , u dont click only button , u pressed everything (also below)

u pressed a button , button pressed a DIV , div pressed a window ...... using propagation , u can control it easy